# Is there a formal terminology to describe $X^T \beta - X^T\hat{\beta}$?

Tags: linear-model, terminology, residuals, error

We know that a linear model is represented as

\begin{align}
y = X^T \beta + \epsilon
\end{align}
where $\epsilon$ is some unobserved error and $\beta$ are the population parameter(s).

Let us define $f(\beta) = X^T\beta$ as the true model for the given data. Since $\beta$ is unobserved, we can't determine $f(\beta)$, so we instead approximate it with a method such as least squares, giving us a $\hat{\beta}$ that we can use to obtain an approximate model for $f(\beta)$:
$$
\hat{y} = X^T\hat{\beta}
$$

We know that formally, the residual is defined as $r = y - \hat{y}$

$\hat{y}$ is also an approximation of $X^T \beta$. Since this is an approximation, it induces error. My question is what is the name of this error? i.e., 
$$
X^T\beta - X^T\hat{\beta} = (y - \epsilon) - X^T\hat{\beta} \\
= (y- X^T\hat{\beta}) - \epsilon \\
= r - \epsilon
$$
Is there a formal name for $r - \epsilon$?

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question: "Is there a formal name for r − ϵ?", my answer is likely no.

The 'r' is the residual error term as is know (and computed) from regression's model fit (observed y - fitted).

The 'ϵ', also referred to as simply 'error' (observed y - actual y), is generally unobserved (unless one is model testing and knows the actual error distribution and/or, for example, the autoregressive error structure, etc. or, more generally, referred to as the data generation process, [see remarks here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_difference_between_error_terms_and_residuals_in_econometrics_or_in_regression_models)).

I would describe the quantity r − ϵ as the difference between estimated error and actual error.